# How to find sales group by pack_id

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

Here is the data we have for working with:
 - we know the package ID and the price of each package ID
 - this means we can find sales by multiplying the count (pack_id_ with the individual price of a package
 - we know that the package_id is found in the subscription table and the pack_price is found in the price table
-  We are supposed to return the values ordered by pack_id.

```
SELECT Count(pack_id) * pack_price 
FROM   package 
       natural JOIN subscription 
GROUP  BY pack_id
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly the result are you are getting? And how they differ from what you expect?

Comment: We are getting the following error message:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

The result we would be expecting is: 

A list of all package ids on the left-hand side with the total sale for them on the right-hand column.  In other words: A summary of sales for any given day, categorized by Package type

Comment: (we also need some kind of where date = ... clause but we are just trying to make the first portion of this query work.  we figured we would try to just get the sales by pack_id before restricting it to a specific date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the error message because you are using the count(pack_id) to multiply with the price, which would cause an aggregate error in the group by.

The way around this would be to use ;with to create a combined query:

```
WITH
count_packid AS 
   ( select 
     count(pack_id) as packcount, pack_id from package group by pack_id),
sales_price AS
  (
    select pack_price, pack_id
    from subscription
  )
SELECT packcount * pack_price, a.pack_id
FROM count_packid a
LEFT JOIN sales_price b on a.pack_id = b.pack_id
```

This way you get around the problem of using the aggregate function directly in the calculation and you should get the results your require. Unforunately I cannot test this, but it should help you in the right direction.

If you want to include a date or something similar you will have to add the WHERE clause to the respective sub-query (ie. count_packid)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified JanR query,Note the changes

```
WITH
count_packid AS 
   ( select 
     count(pack_id) as packcount, pack_id from package group by pack_id),

SELECT packcount * pack_price, a.pack_id
FROM count_packid a
Inner JOIN subscription b on a.pack_id = b.pack_id
```